# Can I use span tags for making HTML email templates?

Tags: html, html-email, email-validation

This is an HTML email template. I don't know whether Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, Outlook support span tags. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Ofcourse you can use span and linebreak.

Answer (score 4):

Spans and line breaks are some of the fundamental elements in HTML. As such, they're fine for use in email templates where HTML is allowed.